# How do I make a list of all possibilities of the items in a list using AppleScript?

Tags: list, applescript

I am wanting to make a list using AppleScript which would follow the following rules with a input list, So say my input was

```
 a
 b
 c
```

I'd want that list to make something like, if my length is 3,

```
 aaa
 aab
 aac
 aba
```

Then eventually end up "ccc"

How can I iterate through a list of items to generate a full list of all combinations?

There should be about 23 or so possibilities to this three digit list with a length of 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is a site where users get help with writing code when they hit a stumbling block and need help working through the problem. So it is expected that you show that you are working on code not looking for someone to write it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set myList to words of (do shell script "echo {a,b,c}{a,b,c}{a,b,c}")
```

Comment: That might work (I know shell scripting but not applescript), but this is really a shell solution, not an applescript solution.

Comment: this is a great solution as running shell commands to manipulate lists is much more time efficient. +1

Comment: The exact syntax of this can be used similar to the other answer, but this gives a more instantaneous response, rather than waiting 50 or so hours for the completion of the program. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's 27:

```
set inputlist to {"a", "b", "c"}
set outputlist to {}

repeat with i1 in inputlist
    repeat with i2 in inputlist
        repeat with i3 in inputlist
            copy i1 & i2 & i3 to the end of outputlist
        end repeat
    end repeat
end repeat

return outputlist
```

result:
{"aaa", "aab", "aac", "aba", "abb", "abc", "aca", "acb", "acc", "baa", "bab", "bac", "bba", "bbb", "bbc", "bca", "bcb", "bcc", "caa", "cab", "cac", "cba", "cbb", "cbc", "cca", "ccb", "ccc"}

Comment: This answer would have worked for me, if it wasn't so time consuming. It's a great little script if I needed a individual string to do something with individually one at a time. Thanks for your answer though. I'll probably bookmark it on my iCloud for reference.